# Simplify a function with empty observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Is there any other way to write the following function?

```
getStation(id) {
    if (id) {
        return this.httpClient.get('/api/stations/edit/' + id, {})
    }else {
        return Observable.empty();
    }
}


getStation(id) {
    return id ? this.httpClient.get('/api/stations/edit/' + id, {}) : Observable.empty();
}
```

I was wondering whether there was a way to remove the `else` part and by default, if there is no return to the function, return an empty Observable.

```
getStation(id): Observable<any>
```

But this doesn't work that way.

(it's all about curiosity... I will use the "else" to my code)

Comment: No, you can't give some kind of default return purely from defining the method. If you say it returns `Observable<any>`, you have to do that explicitly at some point.

Comment: So...you want something that does exactly what the `else` does, but isn't an `else` or ternary?  I'm not really sure what your goal is here.

Comment: You can specify that it can potentially return multiple types, though.  Just have to use the pipe symbol between the types.    Observable<any>  |  otherTypeHere  . Its usually not good practice however.

Comment: (it's all about curiosity... I will use the "else" to my code)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if necessarily better,but you could use a decorator:

```
function DefaultObservable(target,  prop) {
    let original: Function = target[prop];
    target[prop] = function() {
        return original.apply(this, arguments) || Observable.empty();
    }
}

class MyClass {
    @DefaultObservable
    getStation(id) {
        if (id) {
            return this.httpClient.get('/api/stations/edit/' + id, {});
        }
    }
}
```

The decorator warps your original function so that it returns a default value if the value returned from the original function is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

See https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/18/typescript-2-0-the-never-type  to learn about the 'never' operator.

Rather than return an empty observable, you can tell typescript that the function might never return anything.

```
getStation(id) : Observable<any> | never   { 
    if (id) {
          return this.httpClient.get('/api/stations/edit/' + id, {})
    }
}
```

What's your use case for this? Rather than passing 'undefined' as a parameter to that method, couldn't you just check for id elsewhere in your code and only call the method if id exists?